# Spring Initalizr - Custom Project Settings for Intellij

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

is there a way to modify / customize the first page ('Project Settings') of the Spring Initializr, containing the artifact name, build-type, java version, etc. to add a new custom selection?

I'd like to add an application-type selection (and some other settings), which i want to use to generate my Java projects. (see screenshot)

```
Application-type: *Web   *Library
```

If there is a chance to modify the project setting screen, do Intellij support custom settings?

Thank you for you help

[image: modified spring initalizr]

Comment: It's possible to select "Web" framework on the next step.

Comment: i know, but i can't rely only on the dependency selection. I prefer a setting selection before adding dependencies. Like a company-department selection

Comment: No. This UI is driven by a metadata specification and custom fields are not supported.